# What does `$protected dates` accomplish in Eloquent models

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, php-carbon

I was writing a simple test to evaluate saving a future publish date for a saved article. This is how I send data with publish date for tomorrow

```
    $response = $this->putJson('/api/blogs/' . $blogPost->slug, [
        'blog' => [
            'publish' => true,
            'publish_date' => Carbon::today()->addDays(1),
        ]
    ]);
    $response->assertStatus(200);
```

At the controller I save it as follows

```
    $blogData = $request->json()->all()['blog'];
    $blog->fill($blogData);
    $blog->save();
```

I get the following error while running the test

```
[2020-02-13 09:42:11] local.ERROR: Unexpected data found.
Trailing data {"userId":6,"exception":"[object] (InvalidArgumentException(code: 0): Unexpected data found.
Trailing data at /Users/anadi/Code/website/adminpanel/vendor/nesbot/carbon/src/Carbon/Traits/Creator.php:576)
[stacktrace]
#0 /Users/anadi/Code/website/adminpanel/vendor/nesbot/carbon/src/Carbon/Traits/Creator.php(598): Carbon\\Carbon::rawCreateFromFormat('Y-m-d H:i:s', '2020-02-14T00:0...', NULL)
#1 /Users/anadi/Code/website/adminpanel/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Support/DateFactory.php(217): Carbon\\Carbon::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:i:s', '2020-02-14T00:0...')
#2 /Users/anadi/Code/website/adminpanel/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Support/Facades/Facade.php(261): Illuminate\\Support\\DateFactory->__call('createFromForma...', Array)
#3 /Users/anadi/Code/website/adminpanel/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Concerns/HasAttributes.php(813): Illuminate\\Support\\Facades\\Facade::__callStatic('createFromForma...', Array)
#4 /Users/anadi/Code/website/adminpanel/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Concerns/HasAttributes.php(835): Illuminate\\Database\\Eloquent\\Model->asDateTime('2020-02-14T00:0...')
#5 /Users/anadi/Code/website/adminpanel/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Concerns/HasAttributes.php(580): Illuminate\\Database\\Eloquent\\Model->fromDateTime('2020-02-14T00:0...')
#6 /Users/anadi/Code/website/adminpanel/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.php(329): Illuminate\\Database\\Eloquent\\Model->setAttribute('publish_date', '2020-02-14T00:0...')
#7 /Users/anadi/Code/website/adminpanel/app/Http/Controllers/BlogPostController.php(102): Illuminate\\Database\\Eloquent\\Model->fill(Array)
```

When I remove

```
protected $dates = ['deleted_at','publish_date'];
```

from the eloquent model, this error does not occur. Which brings me to my question, what does this line above do?

Comment: Probably mean that the `$dates` property is `protected`. Based on OOP, the private and protected properties are not directly accessed from outside the object. To solve that issue you have two options. The first option is to use getter methods in your class and use those methods instead to access the given properties. The second solution is to make those properties public, but in this case,you decrease your code security level.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually this line turns those fields into Carbon objects and it will help laravel to know that these are date fields. 
For example :
If you write this line in your model 
protected $dates = ['deleted_at','publish_date'];
You can use $model->publish_date->format('d/m/Y') to format date.